# ADF Azure Data-Factory Concating syntax

Tags: azure-data-factory

i'm trying to run a pipeline  that results the names of specific Databases (**@item().USERNAME**) with the same table name - **Stores** . I created a  pipeline with lookup and for each that works fine .
however when I want to filter the tables to only the coulmns I want ( within the for each copy data activity )  - I cant find the right syntax

i tried - @concat ( select CODE_NO,CITY,STREET
from **@item().USERNAME.STORES**) but i'm getting errors

Anyone can help me fix this ? thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That second @ symbol is not needed when using a nested function in ADF.

Try

`@concat('SELECT CODE_NO, CITY, STREET FROM ', item().USERNAME.STORES)`

Or

`@concat('SELECT CODE_NO, CITY, STREET FROM ', string(item().USERNAME.STORES))`

The second one may not be necessary, depending on your confidence in the data types being passed into the ForEach.

Answer (score 1):

If the intend is to have a SQL query like

SELECT CODE_NO,CITY,STREET FROM **someDbName**.Store
I think we can use

```
@concat('SELECT CODE_NO, CITY, STREET FROM  ', item().USERNAME,'.STORES')
```